# Pytest: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Tags: python, pytest, travis-ci

I'm starting to learn pytest and I want to integrate it with Travis later on. I've created my first tests and I can run them from PyCharm without any problem. But when I try to run pytest from Linux's terminal I get the following error:

```
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test_prob.py:1: in <module>
    from src.agents import prob
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I've found some similar problems and solutions for them but none of them have worked for me. [My project structure looks as follow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgChf.png)

Comment: Looks like pycharm is using a virtualenv in the "venv" directory, but on the CLI you are not using it.

Comment: can you show where you are running the tests from? often it's a linux PATH env or PYTHONPATH mismatch that causes import errors. Try `from proj_name.src.agents import prob`

Comment: I think you need an empty \_\_init\_\_.py in the src/ directory. init is a file that tells Python to treat the directory as a Python module.

Comment: I faced a similar issue, I resolved it with the help of this [article](https://medium.com/@dirk.avery/pytest-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-requests-a770e6926ac5)

Comment: @rite2hhh I don't know if it is what you were asking for:
`(venv) arek@arek-GL62-6QC:~/Documents/AI_classes/Projekt/proj_lokalizacja$ pytest`

Comment: @tobhai This article didn't solve my problem unfortunately :/

Comment: @AlexWeavers I've already tried this and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @cropyeee, that's what I was asking for, thanks. Like I mentioned. try `from proj_lokalizacja.src.agents import prob`. Ideally you want to traverse the "package" from the top-level directory which is added to the PATH, so in this case it is `proj_lokalizacja`. This might not be ideal, so the best way is to compare the environments for both Pycharm and Linux shell

Answer (score 13):

I ran into the same issue, and my solution was to execute `pytest` as a module.

```bash
python -m pytest
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have marked `src` as a "Source Root" directory in PyCharm (blue color for the directory indicates that), which means that it's added to the PATH.

That's why it works in PyCharm and not from the shell. Your PyCharm and terminal environments have different `PATH`'s set.

Try to change the import from

```
from src.agents import prob
```

to

```
from proj_lokalizacja.src.agents import prob
```

alongside with running `pytest` from the same location (as we discussed in the comments)

If you do not wish to change your import statements, you'll have to update the `PATH` environment variable to also include `src` directory

Comment: Following a standard project directory structure I find that I'm going to *have* to do *something* to make imports in tests work for the normal `pytest` invocation from the project root. The least intrusive of all the hacks to make the "standard" `test` directory location work is updating `PYTHONPATH` in the `venv` `activate` script. I presume this is equivalent to doing what IDEs always do anyway. It seems IDEs can do whatever crap they like and no-one calls it a hack. If you use `tox` for your tests you don't need this but then your tests are at arms length.